# Failed to upgrade to WebSocket vs. An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, devise, actioncable

Using Rails 5 and ActionCable

"Failed to upgrade to WebSocket" vs. "An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected".
Can someone tell me the difference between these two errors and under which functions they can happen? I believe "An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected" happens on

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
```

And I do have:

```
def find_verified_user 
  if verified_user = env['warden'].user
    verified_user
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure about the the upgrade error.

What I'm really trying to do is catch when a timed out user (not logged out, but timed out), attempts to send a message. So I don't think I'd have to catch this on connection, but on a request. Is there any way to handle an error on request?

The end goal here is to redirect a timedout user to the sign in page when they attempt to send a message. Right now, if a timed out user sends a message, the message just doesn't show up when they hit send, with no indication to the user as to why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected" happens as the immediate result of the `reject_unauthorized_connection` call.

"Failed to upgrade to WebSocket" happens as the result of the `connect` calling `reject_unauthorized_connection`. It means that your socket connection attempt has failed and you didn't switch ("upgrade") from the HTTP mode to the WebSockets mode.

If I wanted to implement a timed out user right to send messages, I would simply save in the database the last sent message time - checking it before each new message.